# Allowing access to redis port for only specific servers with ufw

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, redis, ufw

I've installed ufw on my Ubuntu 10.04 server. The only thing running on that server is going to be ElasticSearch and Redis. Redis uses port 6379. I only want two different IPs to be able to access the IP address of this machine on that port. I ran the following command:

```
sudo ufw allow from xx.xx.xx.x1 to any port 6379
sudo ufw allow from xx.xx.xx.x2 to any port 6379
sudo ufw status

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
6379                       ALLOW       xx.xx.xx.x1
6379                       ALLOW       xx.xx.xx.x2
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
```

To me it appears as if those two IPs should then be able to access that IP address on that server. But they aren't able to make a connection. Are there other ports I need to open for this to be able to happen?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Deleting the follow rule fixed it such that only those IPs were able to connect.

```
ufw delete allow 8080

8080                         ALLOW       Anywhere
```